# What would be a proper way to build a web-based application interface to avoid html manipulation?

Tags: web-applications

I am currently building a web application where users can place stocks trades. So far I use plain HTML, JS, CSS (forms, AJAX calls, etc.) for the frontend and Django/Python at the backend.

I am now wondering how I can build a compiled application interface in order to increase both speed and security when placing trades? For example when I go to the browser based trading terminal of my broker, I can't look into the html source code etc. so it seems they use something like a compiled frontend?

How do they accomplish this and what are common solutions to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... how I can build a compiled application interface ...

Unlike browser-based applications, executables have to be compiled for (and deployed to and tested on) each target operating system.  That's no small job.  If you really *want* to spend the rest of your career fire-fighting the latest Microsoft update that's broken your favourite Windows UI widget, Good Luck. 
At least writing browser-based applications, you're working ion a more insulated world (although not entirely without its own "challenges").

> ... to increase both speed and security ...

What makes you think a compiled application will be any more *secure* that what you have now?

OK, people can't look at the HTML source code, but what does that matter?  There shouldn't be anything "sensitive" held at the client end anyway.  You should regard it as completely untrustworthy.  That's why we have TLS, server-side validation and authentication and all those other, Good Things that we jealously guard on our servers.

What makes you think it will be any *faster* than what you have already?

*By far* the slowest operation in all this will be pushing the request to the server and waiting for the response.  Just making the client application go [a tiny] bit faster is not going to make any major inroads into that.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done. Anything on the end user's system can be manipulated. More so, attackers can send web requests without using your frontend. This applies to *any* frontend, including not just web apps but also compiled applications.

It's your job to validate any and every request your backend receives, since you cannot ever guarantee that the frontend hasn't been compromised by the machine that it was loaded on.

> when I go to the browser based trading terminal of my broker, I can't look into the html source code etc

If this is a web page loaded in a browser of your choosing, you can access the HTML. They may have *obfuscated* the HTML/JS to make your life harder; but you can still access it.

I cannot stress this enough, **obfuscation is not security**.